# Can I update local browser cache by a changelog file

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-loading

We have a single-page website.You don't need download any static files after your first login. The question is every time we upgrade our website,you must reload your static files,and this procedure cost about ten seconds,because the static files amount is so big.

Now,I'm thinking that maybe we can update static file by a update package like what a mobile game do.

Can we?.If not,why.

Comment: are you suggesting a patch to apply to cached content?

Comment: yes，it is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Add the site version number as a query string parameter to the static files.

For example:

```
<script src="js/static.js?v=1"></script>
```

When you update your page, change the version number.

If you are concerned about performance, look at the files in use.  Perhaps they can be minified and combined.

If they are already minified and combined, break out the files that don't change frequently.